# Provides Oracle's database in-memory?

Tags: oracle, in-memory-database, timesten

I'm trying to find out, if Oracle's newest database release 12c comes per default as an in-memory database or does it use TimesTen for this feature?
According to Wikipedia ([Oracle Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database#Database_options)) it "utilizes TimesTen technology" for "In-Memory Database Cache".
Are those two different databases or is the one like a feature of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new [Oracle 12c In-memory database feature](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/in-memory/overview/index.html) is not the same as TimesTen. It implements a column-store based storage in memory in addition to the traditional row-based format on disk. So your data is held in BOTH formats simultaneously. You choose which tables you want to store in memory. This can allow immense improvement in mixed-workload databases.

It is an extra cost option, not included free even with Enterprise edition. The rationale is that if you are maintaining a separate datamart for your analytics, you could instead do the analytics in real-time right on your OLTP system with the In-memory feature and eliminate the need for a datamart environment and its cost (not to mention all the ETL work you have to do to maintain a datamart).

See: http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/in-memory-column-store-12cr1.php

A short video on it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Yf1ghec0gU

A longer video on it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjkPUg1m6PA